# Multiple postman requests with different data sets

Tags: javascript, arrays, postman

I am trying to post a list of companies, consecutively in Postman and stop the request once complete. I have done the following but it only sends the 1st one. 
My coding experience is little and i have been trying extremely hard to learn but with no teacher or guidance on where to go, it would be much appreciated for positive comments. One day i will be very strong in coding and will help those in my position.

**BODY**

```
{
    "name": "{{company}}
}
```

**PRE-REQUEST SCRIPT**

```
var companies = pm.environment.get("companies");
if (!companies) {
companies = ["Goooooooooogle", "Yahoo!", "Facebook", "Amazon", "Currys", "Orion", "Zienu"];
}

var currentCompany = companies.shift();
pm.environment.set("company", currentCompany);
pm.environment.set("companies", companies);
```

**TESTS**

```
var companies = pm.environment.get("companies"); 
if (companies && companies.length >0){
pm.sendRequest("https://postb.in/5HXHKNhQ", function (err, response) {
    console.log(response.json);
});    
}
else {
 pm.sendRequest(null);
}
```

Comment: Why do not try using a simple bash script and curl ? I think this would be simpler

Comment: @Jérôme i am using JS because this is what i am learning and i didn't know anything about bash script. I will investigate now. Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seem to be correct, I just modified it a little

```
var companies = pm.environment.get("companies");

if (!companies) {
     companies = ["Goooooooooogle", "Yahoo!", "Facebook", "Amazon", "Currys", "Orion", "Zienu"];
}

pm.environment.set("companies", companies);
pm.environment.set("company",  companies.shift());
```

Then use the body (in JSON using RAW entry)

```
{
    "company": {{company}}
}
```

Use `Content-Type: application/json` header

Then create a new collection and add this request to it.

Finally use Postman runner (upper left button), select the good collection and set the correct iteration number.

Postman will execute as many request as iterations, then you can check each request body and see that the content changed.

Hoping helping you.